# Controller option missing in Umbraco solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco

I am currently working on umbraco project. Now I am trying to integrate with MVC I have a couple of issues

1. In my solution I have controller Folder. but when i right click on the Add Controller option Folder, its giving me the error as 
**Could not load file or assembly 'ClientDependency.Core, Version=1.7.0.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.. How do I add controller.**

2.Second issue is I have ADO Entity Model(EDMX) in my umbraco project, It gets added successfully, but its not automatically generating the Context class.But when added ADO EntityModel(EDMX) in my another MVC application all the files are auto generated including the Context class. How can I make auto generating the Context class in my umbraco project.

Got solution to the first point. Replace the dll file ClientDependency.Core, Version=1.4.0.4, but still second one is pending..

Comment: Is your Umbraco project setup as a "Web Site" or a "Web Application"?

Comment: @Nate Web Application.

Comment: @Nate For the point 1, Got controller added to my project, For this I have made modification in Package Config File. 
< defaultRenderingEngine> Mvc< /defaultRenderingEngine>. But For secon one, I am not able to get the DBContext Class getting generated.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you have? You may need to enable T4 transformations.

Comment: @Nate   I am using VS 2010